# Safari MegaMenu c/ hoverIntent problem when rendering over Flash swfobject

Tags: jquery, flash-builder, hoverintent, safari

I have a bizarre problem that recently surfaced. I have some megamenus -- they are coded very simply as unordered lists and use jQuery. There are coded up very much like this SitePoint tutorial found [here](http://blogs.sitepoint.com/2009/03/31/make-a-mega-drop-down-menu-with-jquery/).

Here's my jquery

```
$j('li>a[topnav], li>div[topnav]').hoverIntent({
    sensitivity: 4,
    interval: 100,
    over: ShowMenus,
    timeout: 0,
    out: HideMenus
});
```

We're using the hoverIntent plugin to control the onhover, and offhover events. On our landing page -- we have a flash movie (embedded with swfobject.js) and the megemenu is supposed overlay it -- which is does. But, *unfortunately* -- when the menu opens, all of my menu items **collapse** in Safari.  You can see this effect only when using Safari 5 at [Greenmountaincoffee.com](http://www.greenmountaincoffee.com).  When I  remove the flash animation, the menus work fine and do not collapse.

Has anyone encountered this problem before? Any strategies recommended?

Thx